# Put length constraint in a TextField in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-router

I am taking an input from the user of the card number and wants that the length entered by user must not be less than and more than 12. Here is the declaration of my textfield.

```
<TextField
    id="SigninTextfield"
    label="Aadhaar number"
    id="Aadhar"
    lineDirection="center"
    required={true}
    type="number"
    maxLength={12}
    style={styles.rootstyle}
    erorText="Please enter only 12 digits number"
/>
```

Now I am not understanding whether to use javascript or any event handler for restricting the length.

Comment: From where are you using the TextField Compoennt

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri from react-md/lib

Comment: I can't see any maxLength property http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: I was trying to implement the maxLength and forgot to remove it from code. @Alexis

Comment: The maxLength property is present as a prop but doesn't limit the length of text rather displays a warning if the text exceeds the length, and shows the count on the side .  https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/text-fields?tab=1

Comment: You might want to implement a controlled text field and limit the text size yourself

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found another solution [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5309#issuecomment-270684769).

```
<TextField
    required
    id="required"
    label="Required"
    defaultValue="Hello World"
    onInput = {(e) =>{
        e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
    }}/>
```

Comment: Absolutely, the right way is using `inputProps` but if  the `input type` is `number` your way is the proper way.

Comment: `onInput = {(e) =>{ var InputElement = (e.target as HTMLInputElement); InputElement.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(InputElement.value) ).toString().slice(0,12);
}}`  in my environment .value is not recognised, so used HTMLInputElement.

Comment: if the value starts with 0 ,this does not work, my solution is,  e.target.value = e.target.value.toString().slice(0, 6);

Answer (score 302):

You can set the `maxLength` property for limiting the text in text box.

Instead of `onChange` method you can pass `maxLength` to the `inputProps` (lowercase i, not **I**nputProps) props of `material-ui` `TextField`.

```
<TextField
    required
    id="required"
    label="Required"
    defaultValue="Hello World"
    inputProps={{ maxLength: 12 }}
/>
```

Basically we can edit all input element's native attrs via `inputProps` object.

Link to [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) Api

Comment: this isn't a feature, there is only inputStyle

Comment: Warning: Mind the lowercase `i` in "inputProps", which is totally different with "InputProps" with uppercase `I`. I learnt it the hard way.

Comment: Why does maxLength alone not work? I've seen a lot of maxLength answers, but only this solves the problem?

Comment: @duduwe maxLength alone doesn't work simply because the `<TextField>` does not support this prop

Comment: Warning! This doesn't work with `type="number"`

Comment: this doesn't work on `<Input>` fields if it's set to `type="number"`

Comment: This works on these types: password, search, tel, text, url, email. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength)

Comment: InputProps applies to Input react-component since TextField is composed of smaller components.
inputProps applies to what will be input DOM-element and it gets all of its attributes.

Answer (score 24):

```
    <TextField
      autoFocus={true}
      name="name"
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="placeholder"
      id="filled-basic"
      variant="filled"
      size="small"
      fullWidth
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 25,
      }}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <SearchIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

Comment: thank you, this worked for me while working with adornments

Comment: I've also added this for eslint warning: `// eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-duplicate-props`

Answer (score 11):

```
      <TextField
        id="username"
        name="username"
        label={translate('username')}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        value={values.username}
        error={Boolean(errors.username) && touched.username}
        helperText={(errors.username && touched.username && translate(errors.username))}
        required
        inputProps={{maxLength :20}}

      />
```

Answer (score 8):

Is it worth noting that Material-ui `<TextField />` component doesn not have a `maxlength` property. However, the original html `<input>` does. So you don't really need to create any extra function to get this to work. Just use the base `<input>` attributes using `inputProps`.

The actual answer is this:

```
inputProps={
    {maxLength: 22}
}
// Result => <input maxlength="yourvalue" />
```

What this does is it sets the `maxlength` attribute of the underlying `<input>` resulting in: `<input maxlength="yourvalue" />`. Another important thing to note here is that you use `inputProps` and not `InputProps`. The one you're targeting is the small letter `inputProps`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using MUI 5, version `5.0.6`, due to a support for legacy, you will have to do something like this,

```js
            <TextField
              id="standard-textarea"
              label="A label"
              placeholder="Some text here"
              multiline
              variant="standard"
              defaultValue={"Hello"}
              inputProps={{
                maxLength: 255,
              }}
              InputProps={{
                disableUnderline: true,
              }}
            />
```

The `TextField` supports both `inputProps` and `InputProps`, but some properties don't work vice versa.

`maxLength` does not work as expected in `InputProps`, and a property like `disableUnderline` for the MUI 5 does not work as expected in `inputProps`.

Be careful with a possible `typo` with the `i`.

See the API for more information, https://mui.com/api/text-field/.

Answer (score 6):

I discovered something weird on the behavior between `TextField` and `Input` from Material UI

They are very similar to each other, the problem I see is the following:

On the TextField component, if you use InputProps with capital `"I"`, the Adorments  are shown, but in the other hand if you use it as lowercase "`inputProps`", the `maxLength` Html attribute is TAKEN as `valid`, but not the `adorments`

I ended up using `INPUT` instead of a `TextField` so you can use `adorments` in

```
               <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                error={errors.email}
                id="email"
                label={t("signup-page.label-email")}
                name="email"
                onChange={handleChange}
                inputProps={{
                  endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                      <IconButton aria-label="toggle password visibility">
                        <EmailIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                  ),
                  maxLength: 120,
                }}
              />
```

in the above code the `adorment` is ignored, but `maxLength` taken used as "`inputProps`" camel case

The below code is a working example, as you might see, I embraced it as in the old style within a `Form Control`, the input label and the input "`outlinedInput`"

```
        <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="firstName">Password</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          value={values.firstName}
          autoComplete="outlined"
          name="firstName"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          fullWidth
          error={errors.firstName}
          id="firstName"
          label={t("signup-page.label-firstname")}
          onChange={handleChange}
          autoFocus
          inputProps={{ maxLength: 32 }}
        />
      </FormControl>
```

Solution. My final recommendation, use an **`OutlinedInput`** instead of a **`TextField`**, so you can put in a separated way `Adorments` and also `maxLength`

**Below a working example with `FormControl` `OutlinedInput`, `inputProps` - `maxLength` and an end `Adorment` Icon**

```
      <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          value={values.passwordConfirm}
          variant="outlined"
          required
          fullWidth
          error={errors.passwordConfirm}
          name="passwordConfirm"
          label={t("signup-page.label-password-confirm")}
          type={values.showPasswordConfirm ? "text" : "password"}
          id="password-confirm"
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps= {{maxLength:32}}
          endAdornment= {
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword("passwordConfirm")}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                >
                  {values.showPasswordConfirm ? (
                    <Visibility />
                  ) : (
                    <VisibilityOff />
                  )}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
          }
        />
        {errors.passwordConfirm && (
          <p className="error"> {errors.passwordConfirm} </p>
        )}
      </FormControl>
```

Comment: You are true, `InputProps` adds props to its parent container `div`.

Comment: Keep in mind. The first example in this answer provides `endAdornment ` as a prop of `inputProps` - this is a mistake. it should be `InputProps`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer won't work in Firefox for large numbers (greater than 16 digits). Numbers just behaves in a weird way.

For a 22 length field we ended up using this:

```
<TextField
  required
  validateOnBlur
  field="cbu"
  label="22 dígitos del CBU"
  validate={validate.required}
  type="text"
  inputProps={
    {maxLength: 22}
  }
  onInput={(e) => { e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') }}
```

/>

Basically, native `maxLength` constraint for text fields, plus a conversion  from string to numbers "on the fly".

**Improvement**

Also you may prefer to make this reusable and more semantic.

```
# constraints.js
const onlyNumbers = (e) => { e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') };

# form.js
<TextField
  field="cbu"
  label="22 dígitos del CBU" 
  inputProps={
    {maxLength: 22}
  }
  onInput={(e) => onlyNumbers(e) }
```

Answer (score 2):

The material-design `<TextField />` component haven't any `length` property.

You can create yours in the `onChange()` method.

```
updateTextField(event,value){
  if(value.length <= 12){
     //Update your state
  }
  else{
    //Value length is biggest than 12
  }
}

<TextField
    id="SigninTextfield"
    label="Aadhaar number"
    id="Aadhar"
    lineDirection="center"
    required={true}
    type="number"
    onChange={(e,v) => this.updateTextField(e,v)}
    style={styles.rootstyle}
    erorText="Please enter only 12 digits number"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your change handler, just write.

```
if (event.target.value.length !== maxLength ) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with TextareaAutosize. Unfortunately,

```
inputProps={{ maxLength: 12 }}
```

doesn't work with TextareaAutosize.

The below workaround works for TextareaAutosize and for both text and numbers.
Inspired by the accepted answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130234/5236534

```
onInput = {(e) =>{
    e.target.value = (e.target.value).toString().slice(0,10)
```

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import TextareaAutosize from '@mui/material/TextareaAutosize';

export default function MinHeightTextarea() {
  return (
    <TextareaAutosize
      aria-label="minimum height"
      minRows={3}
      placeholder="Minimum 3 rows"
      style={{ width: 200 }}
      onInput = {(e) =>{
        e.target.value = (e.target.value).toString().slice(0,10)
    }}
        
    />
  );
}
```

Link to demo: [Limiting character length in MUI TextareaAutosize](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ebqkry?file=demo.js)

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextField
id="SigninTextfield"
label="Aadhaar number"
id="Aadhar"
lineDirection="center"
required={true}
type="number"
inputProps={{
maxLength: 20,
}}
style={styles.rootstyle}
erorText="Please enter only 12 digits number"
/>
```

Comment: note to readers, it is inputProps, (smaller i) and not InputProps (i.e. capital I)

Answer (score 1):

We can set using **inputProps** property in the following way

```
import React from 'react'
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from '@mui/material'


export default function Select({
    onChangeInput,
    label,
    name,
    value,
    options,
    placeholder,
    disabled,
    error,
    helpertext,
    required,
    shrink,
    maxLength
}) {

    const _onChange = (e, v) => {
        onChangeInput(v)
    }

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            freeSolo
            fullWidth={true}
            multiple={false}
            margin={'noraml'}
            readOnly={disabled}
            name={name}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label}
            value={value}
            options={options}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            renderInput={params => (
                <TextField {...params}
                    label={label}
                    error={error}
                    required={required}
                    helperText={helpertext}
                    variant={'standard'}
                    inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, maxLength: (maxLength && parseInt(maxLength)) || 99}}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: shrink, style: { fontSize: 18 } }}
                />
            )}
            onInputChange={_onChange}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who still are looking for a solution for the number field, this solution worked fine for me.

```
onInput={(e: any) => {
                  e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value))
                    .toString()
                    .slice(0, 2);
                }}
```

Make sure to use any.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState();
  const limitChar = 12;
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.toString().length <= limitChar) {
      setNum(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form">
      <TextField
        type="number"
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        defaultValue={num}
        value={num}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).