# How can I limit the user input in quantity?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, mern

I can limit the quantity of input if the user use the built in arrow icon inside the `textfield`. But when the user type it, it's not working

[image: User use the keyboard]

```
<TextField variant="outlined" label="Quantity" 
                onChange={(e) => setItemName({...itemName, quantity: e.target.value})} 
                type="number"
                fullWidth name="quantity"  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10, maxLength: 2}}}
                pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$"
                />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939909/put-length-constraint-in-a-textfield-in-react-js does this solves your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
onInput={(e) => {e.target.value > 10 ? e.target.value = 10 : e.target.value}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cater that in your `onChange` handler. Check if the `input` value is greater than `max`, assign the `max` to your `input` value

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  label="Quantity" 
  onChange={(e) => {
     const { target: { value, max } } = e;
     let inputValue = value;
     if (inputValue > max) inputValue = max;
     setItemName({ ...itemName, quantity: inputValue })
  }
  type="number"
  fullWidth
  name="quantity"
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10, maxLength: 2}}}   
  pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$"
/>
```

Comment: OP wants to stop from typing text above 10. `onInput` event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while `onChange` occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed. So this may work for the `setItemName` part, but it won't stop the user from typing a value>10.